# Broken quote mark rendering in bibliography

Tags: bibtex

Does anyone have an idea as to why my bibliography is rendered in this way (see image)? This happens to all @article entries.

[image: Strange Quote Behavior]

The .bib entry is

```
@ARTICLE{MNIST,
author={Lecun, Y. and Bottou, L. and Bengio, Y. and Haffner, P.},
journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
title={Gradient-based learning applied to document recognition},
year={1998},
month=11,
volume={86},
number={11},
pages={2278-2324},
doi={10.1109/5.726791},
ISSN={0018-9219}}
```

I am using cleanthesis.sty with the defaults (bibtex), editing with Texmaker on Windows.

Comment: It is because you, some package you are loading, or `cleanthesis.sty` (not `cleanthesis.cls`?) is likely loading a language module like `german` for either `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be a bit more precise about what you object to in the output. I can't see a broken quotation mark. (They are not your standard English/American quotation marks though, they look like the ones used in German amongst other languages.) What I think a bit meh is the space between the label and the entry which is almost non-existent. But to change that we would need to know more about your document, to that end a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct, it was loading csquotes with german. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the german-style quotes option.

In `cleanthesis.sty`

```
\RequirePackage[                    % advanced quotes
    strict=true,                    %   - warning are errors now
    style=german                    %   - german quotes
]{csquotes}
```

to

```
\RequirePackage[                    % advanced quotes
    strict=true,                    %   - warning are errors now
    style=english                   %   - english quotes
]{csquotes}
```

Comment: I'd rather say that the solution would be avoiding such a rigid style or, at least, asking its author to fix the language dependences of the style.